# How can I bring second sub plot on top of first sub plot using matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataframe `df` which looks as follows:

```
    Min Average Max
Score   30  55  80
```

`df.to_dict` is as follows:

```
{'Min': {'Score': 30}, 'Average': {'Score': 55}, 'Max': {'Score': 80}}
```

I want to plot a bar plot starting from Min to Max, and add the Average in the form of a marker in the bar.
I wrote the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df["Max"].plot(kind = "bar",
              bottom = df["Min"], ax = ax,
              width = 0.1)

ax.scatter(x = 0,
           y = df["Average"],
           marker = "_",
           s = 10000,
           color = "red")

plt.ylim(0, 120)
```

This returned me the plot as shown:
[image]

As observed, the scatter plot or the horizontal red line as marker is hidden by the blue bar. I want to bring it on the front.

I brought the line of code regarding scatter plot before the bar plot as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.scatter(x = 0,
           y = df["Average"],
           marker = "_",
           s = 10000,
           color = "red")

df["Max"].plot(kind = "bar",
              bottom = df["Min"], ax = ax,
              width = 0.1)

plt.ylim(0, 120)
```

But I am still getting the same plot. How can I modify the code such that the marker can come on the front?

Comment: I'm getting the correct plot with your last code... Try to restart the kernel, you never know...

Comment: I am still getting the same plot with the last code, even though I restarted kernel.

Comment: Ohh yeah sorry, I meant I got the correct plot with the first code you posted.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me after I ran it in a separate virtual environment (not base environment) and after starting a fresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code worked for me itself after I ran it in a separate virtual environment (not base environment) and after starting a fresh terminal.
[image]